# Is it bad coding practice to expose your backend server port number in code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, hyperlink, conventions

I'm writing an application using React and Node.js. For my server, I'm using Express and the `dotenv` package to hide my server configurations, such as PORT, which is the port number my backend server runs on. For example, my server has the following environment variable `PORT=5000`.

In my frontend, one of the components have an `<a>` that links to my backend server's root route, `'/'`. When this link is pressed, my browser loads my server's root route. For example, my React component renders the following link `<a href="http://localhost:5000/">Login</a>`.

Is it bad practice to code my server's PORT, 5000, directly into the link of my React component?

Answer (score 1):

All that matters here is that your server is secure from outside attacks.  If your server is secure in that regard, then it already has a public IP address and bad guys will port scan that and find any server that responds, so there's no extra harm in exposing the port number.  As is often said, obscurity is not security anyway.

Besides, there is no TCP server in the world that can be used without exposing the port number of the server.  That's how TCP works.  So, if you're going to expose the server at all to the outside world, then you just have to secure it.  And, you can't hide the port number anyway from port scanners.

So, the bigger question for you is whether your backend server is secure, given that random people on the internet can know its public IP address and its port?

Comment: A note regarding nmap scanning: It's illegal in many countries, so even an attempt at scanning your ports is illegal without the required pentest contract. Not that black-hats care at the end of the day, but it does add a layer of protection by giving you some time to detect it.

Comment: @mazunki - I hope you're not thinking that just because port scanning is illegal in some jurisdictions, that nobody does it?  All I have to do is look in my router firewall logs and see how many times someone has attempted to get in and this is a non-published dynamic IP address that is randomly assigned to me by my internet provider.

Comment: Oh, certainly. But it does give a window between the moment they figure out what you have running, and the moment they start the attack for you to do something about it. Laws are not a firewall.

Comment: @mazunki - What gives you a window of time?  Most people never know they've been scanned and found.

Comment: While most people don't, those that care about security should definitely log those kind of things, and probably issue a warning. It's up to the responsible to decide what and when to do whatever.

Comment: @mazunki - I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here.  My point was that your IP address and port are not a secret.  They have to be known for anyone to use your server and they can be discovered by scanners.  So, you have to ALREADY be prepared with an appropriately secured server.  It's not like you wait until you get a security notification that a port scanner has found you to do something.

Comment: At my home, for instance, I don't even have a firewall set up at most times. I run various game servers between me and my friends. It's easier to just let everything through. I do monitor what comes through, though, and in case anything suspicious comes along I will just set up my walls until the threat is over, or change my IP to something else.

Comment: @mazunki - Still not sure what point you're trying to make that is relevant to the OP's question.  Certainly what you're doing is NOT what most people do.

Comment: It was a note on your answer, not strictly to the OP, and I'd say it is relevant to an extent: As long as the OP is careful with what they're doing, they are safe. If they accept the security "as is", they're at risk.